# Saber quantas imagens ou arquivos tem em uma pasta

Tags: javascript

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em laravel e fiz uma seção aonde irá mostrar imagens de fundo a cada 2 segundos.

Meu código js para vocês terem uma ideia.

```
const career = document.getElementById('career');
var index = 1;

function changeBackgroundImage(){
  index += 1;
  if(index < 4){
      career.style.backgroundImage = `url('../../../images/pages/index/career/${index}.jpg')`;
  }else{
      index = 1;
      career.style.backgroundImage = `url('../../../images/pages/index/career/${index}.jpg')`;
  }
}
setInterval('changeBackgroundImage()', 2000)
```

Eu queria saber como faço em javascript para contar quantas imagens tem dentro desta pasta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Isso não é possível usando apenas JavaScript!

Você pode fazer uma chamada Ajax para uma página que acessa a **pasta no servidor** e retorna o resultado esperado, mas é importante lembrar que a pasta **não deve estar na máquina cliente**.

**Referência:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/1266009/5626568

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Eu que agradeço o retorno e fico feliz por ter ajudado.